# Chrome is being controlled by automated test software

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I am running automated tests in Chrome with Serenity BDD (Selenium).

I had to download a new ChromeDriver, because my tests could not run -> The test would open ChromeDriver but could not "Browse as user". When I googled the issue, they said I had to update ChromeDriver.

So I updated ChromeDriver to version 2.28 and I also updated the Chrome version to Version 57.0.2987.98.

But now - EVERY TIME I run my tests this annoying text comes up:

> Chrome is being controlled by automated test software

And it asks me if I want to save password. (I can't add pictures because I don't have enough "points")

In the previous version, I had managed to block these 2 things by:

```
public class CustomChromeDriver implements DriverSource {

    @Override
    public WebDriver newDriver() {
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
            String proxyServer = String.format("AProxyIDontWantToDisplay", System.getenv("proxy.username"), System.getenv("proxy.password"));
            proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyServer);
            capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--no-sandbox","--ignore-certificate-errors","--homepage=about:blank","--no-first-run"));
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            return driver;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean takesScreenshots() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know there is this one ([A link to same issue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26051/chrome-driver-2-28-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notif)),
but there are too many answers that don't work.

Anybody that knows how to remove that?

Comment: About the "controlled by automation" text pop up: is there an issue it's causing? I was messing with the chrome driver the other day and it didn't show up screenshots, etc, and wasn't causing any element interaction issues.

Comment: No not really, i have some components under that pop up that wont be shown in screenshots when they are clicked. thats why :)

Comment: Is this able to navigate URL and interact elements ?

Comment: @BobbyB did you try taking the screenshot and seeing if they were covered? Like I stated, I didn't see the popup in the screenshots I took the other day.

Answer (score 39):

Add this to the options you pass to the driver:

```
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

Comment: That answer was from over 3 years ago. Chrome might have changed the argument. [This might help](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification)

Comment: don't work for me in JavaScript

Answer (score 32):

Previously, passing the "disable-infobars” ChromeOption to the WebDriver prevented Chrome from displaying this notification. Recently, the "disable-infobars" option has been deprecated and no longer removes the notification. The current workaround for this is to pass in an option called "excludeSwitches" and then exclude the "enable_automation" switch.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"}); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This solution does not stop the notification from being displayed when used in Java.

Only `options.addArguments("disable-infobars");` works fine

Comment: To disable Notifications add this : 
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

Comment: While I agree that in nearly all cases it won't affect your testing, in my case it did, big time.  The application I was trying to automate was not adjusting the screen drawing to the reduced real-estate when the info-bar was displayed and consequently critical elements that I needed to confirm as clickable were not because they were obscured by other elements.  This is clearly a programming/design issue by the developers, but disabling the info-bars fixed my problem, the screen displayed correctly when they were gone.

Comment: disable-infobars is not supported anymore for the latest drivers (76.0). Check @Rajeev 's answer for java and my answer for C#.

Comment: @BillHileman I have modified the answer with the latest working code

Comment: Is there a way to disable the warning via cli flags?

Answer (score 12):

"disable-info" switch is not supported anymore for the latest chromedrivers. (at least 76.0).
@Rajeev's answer works and here I write the counterpart for C#.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: This is woked for me

Comment: Hi @David Piao, I don't have any AddAdditionalOption method on ChromeOptions class, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are using C#/Selenium?

Comment: if you don't have `AddAdditionalOption`, check for `AddAdditionalCapability`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's very dissatisfying that there is no comprehensive resource for Chrome capabilities...

Answer (score 8):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Use the above codes for latest Chrome drivers.

Answer (score 6):

**Works on 2022**

**remove Chrome is being controlled by automated test software in python**

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
URL = "https://google.com/"
driver.get(URL)
```

Answer (score 5):

Tried many of these suggested solutions, but none of them worked. OK, my code is in C#, so there might be some differences in the WebDriver implementations for different platforms.

Anyway, the solution that I got working was using the following options for Chrome when running on .NET.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExcludedArguments("enable-automation");
```

On .NET there doesn't seem to be any `setExperimentalOption()` method on the `ChromeOptions` class.

Comment: Jan 2023 - This solution works great on my part.

Answer (score 4):

While the `disable-infobars` route will work, it will likely suppress the infobar in all cases (as suggested [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/26262/29072)), not just the case that the OP is referring to. This is overkill at best, and could lead to unexpected and inexplicable behavior in the future if you are not getting some important message.

I think it's better to leverage the provided [`enable-automation`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-automation) switch by ***disabling it*** in the [`excludeSwitches`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) area of your config/setup while doing nothing with regards to `disable-inforbars`. The `enable-automation` switch's description:

> Inform users that their browser is being controlled by an automated test.

For `nightwatch.conf.js` it would look something like this (and worked for me):

```
desiredCapabilities: {
  ...
  chromeOptions: {
    excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'],
    ...
  }
}
```

This should only do what we are after: getting rid of that specific pesky message!

**Edit [2017-11-14]**: This is now causing an even more annoying `Disable Developer Mode Extensions` alert/warning. I've tried every relevant-looking flag/switch I could find that might help, but to no avail. I've filed a bug with Chromium, so we'll see and I'll try to swing back through here if I get a resolution.

Answer (score 3):

"disable-infobars" flag has been deprecated, but you can avoid this message by adding the following:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

May someone needs this for Capybara, Watir should be like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  $driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :args => [ "--disable-infobars" ]})
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Protractor solution:**

I arrived here searching for a **Protractor** solution, if useful for anyone I found, with help from the above answers; with Protractor you can add Chrome specific options to the chromeOptions object, within the capabilities object in the protractor.config file, for example to use the disable-infobars option discussed above use the following:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['disable-infobars']
  }
},
```

To use the enable-automation also discussed above:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation']
  }
}
```

disable-infobars is preferred in my circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, with this code I am able to disable **Chrome is being controlled by automated test software** as well as the **Save password popup**`

```
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//To Turns off multiple download warning
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

prefs.put( "profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1 );

//Turns off download prompt
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
                    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
//To Stop Save password propmts
prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
//To Disable any browser notifications
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
//To disable yellow strip info bar which prompts info messages
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Chromedriver path");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Log.info("Chrome browser started");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by using **addArguments(array("disable-infobars"))**

This is for **facebook/php-webdriver**

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(array("disable-infobars"));
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
$this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
options1.add_argument("--app=https://www.google.com.ph")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every option from GitHub currently with those options I don't get additional browser page.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # this changes the behavior 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

**Version info**

```
2023-12-28 Thu 17:55  
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 120.0.6099.129
pip list | grep selenium
selenium               4.16.0
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is using **Rails 5.1+**, which changed the testing structure a bit and Capybara is configured in this file now for system tests:

```
application_system_test_case.rb
```

You can add **"args"** in the options for **driven_by** like this:

```
driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400], options: { args: ["--disable-infobars"] }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public WebDriver SetupChromeDriver(){
        //Initialize Chrome Driver
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); 
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Importent Softwares/Chrome Driver/chromedriver_2.37.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        return driver;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It took a lot of fiddling but eventually I found a combination of flags that **works in 2021!**

This tells Chrome to ignore all SSL errors, disables the "*Chrome is being controlled by automated test software*" message and starts in full screen.
Add it to the Target field of your shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --test-type=webdriver --start-fullscreen
```