# "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" error in Chrome 80

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using C# Selenium and Chrome in 80, and Chrome says

> Chrome is being controlled by automated test software

I need to disable that, I am using NuGet Packages

```
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver  80.0.3987  
Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0
```

I input code in C#

```
option.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
```

How can I do?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782058/5386938

Comment: I tried that, but they say 'Disable developer mode extensions'

Comment: So, why not do that?