# Not able to use chrome with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

pretty brief question.....
when i use selenium with python and open google chrome it opens a new windows saying"Chrome is controlled by automated test software" and not in a normal window what should i do?
thanks

Comment: This is a normal chromedriver behavior. What did you expect?

Comment: can i fix it? or do anything about it?

Comment: i am following a course on selenium... the teacher did it without any problem? what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to fix it. Everything in this case goes well. Why did you decide that it does not work correctly?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143014/chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome is being controlled by automated test software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143014/chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software)